# Чи потрібна кома у конструкції "звучить як"?

Tags: пунктуація

У вірші І. Малковича ["Військо"](http://poetyka.uazone.net/malkovych/virshi05.html) коми немає:

> **Звучить як** міт: відважне військо...

Однак на багатьох інших сайтах, зокрема у поширенні ТСН ["Найкращі музичні коуби"](https://www.facebook.com/tsn.ua/videos/1374204285971342/) є й інша версія:

> **Звучить, як** у пісні.

То як насправді має бути?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оскільки це речення **звучить як міт**, **як**  має значення *«у ролі кого, чого»*, тому можна не ставити коми. Однак, можна інтерпретувати це речення **звучить (ніби) міт**, тому можна поставити кому ( як перед порівняльним зворотом) . На мою думку, важливу роль грає авторське бачення (оскільки це поезія). В реченні **звучить як  у(наче) пісні**, кому перед **як** потрібно ставити, оскільки це кома перед порівняльним [зворотом](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC/).